# Turbo Boost is not working, for Intel core i7 CPU

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, cpu, bios, intel-core-i7

Recently I changed the motherboard of my laptop (hp envy 15t-j100) with new one, the laptop is working good. But the processor (core i7 4700 MQ) now does not run in turbo boost mode any more, the task manager show maximum speed of 2.4 GHz. The BIOS version is F65 and I can not figure any way to make turbo boost run from the BIOS or from any another place! Any Help please?

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  It would appear that you have accidentally created two accounts.  You should use the [contact form](/contact) and select “I need to merge user profiles” to have your accounts merged.  In order to merge them, you will need to provide links to the two accounts.   For your information, these are https://superuser.com/users/733280/parc-roi and https://superuser.com/users/733290/parc-roi.   You’ll then be able to [edit], comment on, and accept answers to this question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by updating my BIOS from version F65 to F69 and TurboBoost started working again.